# How build from source multiple services with docker-compose and create a single image?

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, celery

I'm trying to create multiple containers for my Python/Django application called `controller` and I would like the containers to run in a single image, not two. The problem is that my file `docker-compose.yml` build two services from source and it generates two separated images as a result. The application is composed of 5 services: a Django project, Celery (worker, beat, flower) and Redis.

How can I tell docker-compose to build the `django` and `redis` service from source and to create all services in the same image ?

I've tried to change `image: image: controller-redis` with `image: controller` and it create a unique image with all services, but most of them failed to start because files aren't found :

Logs output :

```
$ docker-compose logs -f
controller-celery_beat-1    | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: 24: exec: /start-celerybeat: not found
controller-django-1         | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: 24: exec: /start: not found
controller-flower-1         | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: 24: exec: /start-flower: not found
[...]
controller-celery_worker-1  | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: 24: exec: /start-celeryworker: not found
```

Docker-compose ps

```
$ docker-compose ps
NAME                         COMMAND                  SERVICE             STATUS              PORTS
controller-celery_beat-1     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   celery_beat         exited (127)        
controller-celery_worker-1   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   celery_worker       exited (127)        
controller-django-1          "docker-entrypoint.s…"   django              exited (127)        
controller-flower-1          "docker-entrypoint.s…"   flower              exited (127)        
controller-redis-1           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   redis               running             6378-6379/tcp
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  django:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/django/Dockerfile
    image: controller
    command: /start
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
    env_file:
      - controller/.env
    depends_on:
      - redis
    networks:
      - mynetwork

  redis:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/redis/Dockerfile
    image: controller-redis # <------------------ modification was done here
    expose:
      - "6378"
    networks:
      - mynetwork

  celery_worker:
    image: controller
    command: /start-celeryworker
    volumes:
      - .:/app:/controller
    env_file:
      - controller/.env
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - controller
    networks:
      - mynetwork

  celery_beat:
    image: controller
    command: /start-celerybeat
    volumes:
      - .:/app:/controller
    env_file:
      - controller/.env
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - controller
    networks:
      - mynetwork

  flower:
    image: controller
    command: /start-flower
    volumes:
      - .:/app:/controller
    env_file:
      - controller/.env
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - controller
    networks:
      - mynetwork

networks:
  mynetwork:
    name: mynetwork
```

**compose/local/django/Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.10

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y build-essential \
  && apt-get install -y libpq-dev \
  && apt-get install -y gettext \
  && apt-get install -y git \
  && apt-get install -y openssh-client \
  && apt-get install -y libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl-dev \
  && apt-get install -y nano \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

COPY ./compose/local/django/entrypoint /entrypoint
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint

COPY ./compose/local/django/start /start
RUN chmod +x /start

COPY ./compose/local/django/celery/worker/start /start-celeryworker
RUN chmod +x /start-celeryworker

COPY ./compose/local/django/celery/beat/start /start-celerybeat
RUN chmod +x /start-celerybeat

COPY ./compose/local/django/celery/flower/start /start-flower
RUN chmod +x /start-flower

WORKDIR /app

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint"]
```

**compose/local/redis/Dockerfile**

```
FROM redis

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y wget \
  && wget -O redis.conf 'http://download.redis.io/redis-stable/redis.conf' \
  && mkdir /usr/local/etc/redis \
  && cp redis.conf /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf

RUN sed -i '/protected-mode yes/c\protected-mode no' /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf \
  && sed -i '/bind 127.0.0.1 -::1/c\bind * -::*' /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf \
  && sed -i '/port 6379/c\port 6378' /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf

CMD [ "redis-server", "/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf" ]

WORKDIR /app
```

**compose/local/django/start**

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o errexit
set -o pipefail
set -o nounset

python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001
```

**compose/local/django/celery/beat**

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o errexit
set -o nounset

rm -f './celerybeat.pid'

# watch only .py files
watchfiles \
  --filter python \
  'celery -A controller beat -l info --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler'
```

**compose/local/django/celery/worker**

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o errexit
set -o nounset

# watch only .py files
watchfiles \
  --filter python \
  'celery -A controller worker --loglevel=info -Q controller_queue_1,controller_queue_2,default'
```

**compose/local/django/celery/flower**

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o errexit
set -o nounset

worker_ready() {
    celery -A controller inspect ping
}

until worker_ready; do
  >&2 echo 'Celery workers not available'
  sleep 1
done
>&2 echo 'Celery workers is available'

celery -A controller  \
    --broker="${CELERY_BROKER}" \
    flower
```

**Projects files**

```
docker-compose.yml
controller/
    compose/
        local/
            django/
                Dockerfile
                entrypoint
                start
                celery/
                    beat/
                        start
                    flower/
                        start
                    worker/
                        start
            redis/
                Dockerfile
```

Comment: Not an expert but your configuration seems fine to me. Have you tried to rerun `docker-compose build` after making changes ?

Comment: Yes I did, made another build after the change

Comment: Hmm I don't see why your start files don't get picked up

Comment: For some reason it builds only the `redis` image

Comment: A Docker image usually contains a single self-contained thing and its source dependencies.  Is there a reason you want to include the independent Redis server in your application image?  (Would it make sense to include it in the Python source code?)  Can you use the Docker Hub `redis` image instead of building your own?

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks for answering. I wanted to include the Redis service into the image to limit to the number of images I need to manage and host in my private registry. I also though about including Redis inside the Python image with `apt-get` but unfortunnatly I couldn't found tutorial to do that.